# Invoke function with stored procedure as parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I have the following function in C# which is working fine

```
private void AddQueue()
{
    SqlConnection conn = forconnection();
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertFormIssue",conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Qdatetime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();          
}
```

Now I want the same function but with different stored procedure, I want to reuse this function with another stored procedure.

How do I pass stored procedure as argument?

Comment: Change "spInsertFormIssue" ..? I would probably only make this "generic" if the SPs take the same parameters (eg. differ in name only). Also, see `using` for how to writer cleaner and more robust code.

Comment: @user2864740 i want to reuse this function And SPs parameters are same

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` are both `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the stored procedure name and parameters from request argument.

Like this:

```
private void AddQueue(string spName, List<SqlParameter> SqlParameters)
{
    ...
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, conn);
    ...

    if (SqlParameters.Count > 0)
           cmd.Parameters.AddRange(SqlParameters.ToArray());

    ...
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qdatetime", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = DateTime.Now });

AddQueue("spInsertFormIssue", sqlParameters);
```

Comment: I just want to get name of parameter

Comment: when i use String spName and then when i call this Function e.g AddQueue("spName") its not working and showing error could not find store procedure

Comment: @Raza Error "could not find store procedure" means: Sp name incorrect or parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass name of the stored procedure as parameter:

```
string procedureName = "spInsertFormIssue";
private void AddQueue(string procedureName)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = forconnection();
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName,conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Qdatetime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();          
    }
```

Comment: its not working when i called the function in main body it show error Could not found store procedure

Comment: Maybe because you don't really pass procedureName inside function - examine procedureName variable inside method body